# vertical-align:baseline outer element strange height

Tags: html, css

here is the html code below:

```
<div class="container">
   no Text
   <span class="base">baseline align</span>
</div>
```

css code:

```
div {
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 100px;
    outline: 1px solid red;
}
span {
    font-size: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: wheat;
}
```

my question is why the height of the container element is 107px,not 110px.

```
containerHeight = lineHeight + (spanFont - divFont)/2 = 100px + 10px = 110px
```

- is there any wrong with my calulation?
- here is the fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/zhouxiaoping/46wuvm3x/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider your code snippet, reproduced below, and look at the yellow, right hand element, which has `font-size: 50px` and `line-height: 36px`.  Note that even though the font size is 50px, the vertical space occupied by the character (glyph) is less than 50px, more like 36px.  Fonts are designed so that there is a box that holds the characters and the glyphs/characters are positioned within that box.

The computed overall box height is actually the line-height (100px) plus the difference is the height of the glyph boxes, which is a bit less than the dimensions of the font-size.

Note that if you set the vertical-align value to `top` (or `bottom`) on:

```
<span class="top">baseline span Text</span>
```

then the computed height is 100px, the specified line-height.

The details as to why this works the way it does is found in the CCS2 specification:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#line-height

specifically, the part about leading and half-leading.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $container = $('.container');
  var divHeight = $container.height();
  $('.info').html('container is ' + divHeight + 'px');
})
```

```css
div {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 100px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  position: relative; /* for demo only */
}
span {
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 100px; /* this value is inherited, I show it explicitly */
  display: inline-block;
  background: wheat;
}

/* the following for demo purposes... */
.info {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.top {
  vertical-align: top;
}
.base {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
.line-50 {
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 1px dashed blue;
  outline: none;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.box-50 {
  position: absolute;
  outline: none;
  bottom: 50%;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 36px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="info">x</span>
<br>
<br>
<div class="container">
  test text
  <span class="base">baseline span Text</span>
  <div class="line-50"></div>
  <div class="box-50">Xey</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help,I change the font-family and the height of container is 106~108px,the textBottom - textTop = fontSize,not the baseline